# Notice: Undefined index: branch in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 11

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

```
<?php

    class login
    {
        var $template="login1.tpl";
        var $temp1="mainformm.tpl";

        function login($params,$tpl)
        {

        $branch=$params['branch'];
                $_SESSION['b']=$branch;
             extract($_POST);
            if(!(isset($params['username'])))
            {

                  $tpl->assign("message","Enter Your Password");
                  $tpl->assign("branch",$branch);
                  $tpl->display($this->template);

            }
            else
            {     
                 $username=$params['username']; 
                 require_once("connection.php");    
                 $query="select * from add_users where userid='$username'";
                 $rs=$conn->Execute($query) or die("unable to exec");

                 $found=0; 
                 $uid="";
                 $pwd="";
                 while(!$rs->EOF)
                 {     
                      if(( $rs->fields[0]===$params['username'])and($rs->fields[1]===$params['password']))
                      {  
                        $uid=$rs->fields[0];
                        $pwd=$rs->fields[1];
                        $found=1; 
                        break; 
                       }
                      $rs->MoveNext();
                 }

                 if($found)
                 {
                       $_SESSION['USERNAME']=$username;
                       $_SESSION['PASSWORD']=$password;
                       $tpl->assign('branch',$_SESSION['b']);
                       $tpl->display($this->temp1);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      $tpl->assign("message","Invalid UserName or Password<br>Please Try Again.."); $tpl->assign('branch',$branch);
                      $tpl->display($this->template);
                 } 

                $conn->close();  
            }
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you format your question? It hurts my eyes!

Comment: The error speaks for itself

Comment: My guess is that `$params['branch'];` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

your undefined index is coming from the array `$param` that is one of the function arguments. You need to ensure that `$params['branch']` exists before you set it to a variable. One way to test this is to replace:

```
$branch=$params['branch'];
```

with:

```
if(isset($params['branch'])){
    $branch=$params['branch'];
}else{
    echo "Branch not found in params array";
}
```